# Is it recommended to use Dependency Injection when there is no multiple implementation?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I know that it recommended to use DI when we have multiple implementation of interface. But is there any other benefit that recommend to use DI without having multiple implementation?

Comment: Dependency Injection is a way to apply the Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP). The DIP promotes loose coupling. Loose coupling is applicable independently whether we have multiple implementations or not.

Comment: We have always at least 1 different implemantation which is unit test.

Answer (score 2):

I've often found out, the bigger the solution, the smaller the percentage of the interfaces having multiple implementations. But as @Mikhail pointed out, it's certainly a lot easier to plug in newer implementations should they arise.

However, the strongest benefit of dependency injection is that it can make **testing** a lot easier: by injecting interfaces in the unit under test, you're able to mock those interfaces so that they return some dummy objects that can help you reach certain code paths.

I also think that's easier and more elegant/readable to scale up a project through this inversion-of-control concept, and it's also pretty handy for following a SOLID design.

Answer (score 0):

Just that other implementation(s) might appear in the future.